# Update datatype of primary key without deleting the table

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have created a table *State* which my other table, *Addresses*, references.

```
CREATE TABLE State
(
     StateId varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     Text varchar(40) NOT NULL
)
```

I want to change its primary key to `int` and `IDENTITY(1,1)`, however, I cannot delete it because it is a foreign key for the other table. How can I update it without having to recreate everything?

Comment: You're going to have to drop and re-create the foreign key anyway...

Comment: and don't forget the address table references to the state table. You will need to change that also

Comment: What values does it currently have in it? Are they all things that cast OK to integer? If so do you need the existing values preserved?

Answer (score 10):

You cannot change datatypes of Key fields (Primary or Foreign). You can't even change a datatype if the field is used in an index. So...

### If there is no data in these tables (obviously much easier):

1. Drop Foreign Key on [Addresses] that references [State]
2. Drop Primary Key on [State]
3. `ALTER TABLE [State] DROP COLUMN [StateID];`
4. `ALTER TABLE [State] ADD [StateID] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL;`
5. Recreate Primary Key on [State]
6. `ALTER TABLE [Addresses] ALTER COLUMN [StateID] INT NOT NULL;`
7. Recreate Foreign Key on [Addresses] that references [State]

### If there is data in these tables (and you have a maintenance window):

1. `ALTER TABLE [State] ADD [StateID2] INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL;`
2. `ALTER TABLE [Addresses] ADD [StateID2] INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_Addresses_StateID2] DEFAULT (0);`
3. Update the [Addresses] table to match the new IDs in the [State] table

   ```
   UPDATE addr
   SET    addr.StateID2 = st.StateID2
   FROM   Addresses addr
   INNER JOIN [State] st
           ON st.StateID = addr.StateID
   ```
4. Drop Foreign Key on [Addresses] that references [State]
5. Drop Primary Key on [State]
6. sp_rename [State].[StateID] -> [StateIDold]
7. sp_rename [State].[StateID2] -> [StateID]
8. Recreate Primary Key on [State].[StateID]
9. `ALTER TABLE [Addresses] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_Addresses_StateID2];`
10. sp_rename [Addresses].[StateID] -> [StateIDold]
11. sp_rename [Addresses].[StateID2] -> [StateID]
12. Recreate Foreign Key on [Addresses].[StateID] that references [State].[StateID]
13. Update Stored Procedure(s) or whatever processes/code insert (and possibly update if the StateID field can change) into the [Addresses] table
14. After you are sure that all data is there and matches, then you can drop the [StateIDold] field in both the [State] and [Address] tables.

### If there is data in these tables (and you do *not* have a maintenance window):

If there is no maintenance window then you have to not only deal with contention on the table (and adding / removing fields requires a SCHEMA lock), but you also need to update the process that adds data to the [Addresses]

1. Build copies of both tables [Addresses2] and [State2] with the desired structure (but no FK)
2. Copy the data over to the new tables
3. make sure no data in [Addresses] can change (this is very temporary)
4. rename current tables (e.g. [Addresses] -> [AddressesOld])
5. rename new tables (e.g. [Addresses2] -> [Addresses])
6. Add FK
7. Be sure to update code that inserts into Addresses
8. Allow changes in [Addresses] again

For a more detailed explanation of this "no maintenance window" approach, please see the article I wrote about it on SQL Server Central (free registration required): [Restructure 100 Million Row (or more) Tables in Seconds. SRSLY!](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Data+Modeling/72814/)

Answer (score 2):

Like the comments say, you will have to do something like:

- create a new IDENTITY column in State.
- drop the foreign-key constraint to Address.
- change the datatype of the FK column in Address,
- update the FK column in Address with the new identity value from State,
- drop the old StateID column in State.
- optionally, rename the new IDENTITY column in State to StateID.
- re-create the foreign key.

For the record, renaming database objects or columns may lead to problems with existing views and other database objects.

Find a time when the database load is at a minimum (ideally a service window) and perform the entire change within a transaction - it'll block those two tables for everyone else while it's running, but this prevents anybody else from changing any data while you're performing the schema changes.